# CSS : lineclamp truncating long word

Tags: html, css

I have a title with a format of `{ID} | {title}`, where the titles tend to be very long. I would also like this title to stay to one line, so I have a solution like so :

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
   display: -webkit-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <span class="inner">12334569 | SDFFDSFS_FSFDSSDF_SFSDF_WEFWEFEFWFWFFWEFEWWFWE_SFSDFSFSDFSFSFSFSD_FSDDFSFFSDSFS_FSDFDSFSFS_FSFFSDFSDFSDFSFSFD_FSDFSDF</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue with this is it shortens the entire title because it's a long string. I'm wondering if it's possible to keep the title as a single line and have it truncate only the part of the title string that is extending beyond the first line, for example:

`12334569 | SDFFDSFS_FSFDSSDF_SFSDF_WEFWEFEFWFWFFWEFEWWFWE_SFSDFSFSDFSFSFSFSD_FS...`

I've not been able to find a way to cleanly do this with CSS.

Comment: Please revise your post to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't add tags. See [ask] for tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent text wrapping you can add `white-space: nowrap;` and to inform user that there is more characters you can add `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      12334569 | SDFFDSFS_FSFDSSDF_SFSDF_WEFWEFEFWFWFFWEFEWWFWE_SFSDFSFSDFSFSFSFSD_FSDDFSFFSDSFS_FSDFDSFSFS_FSFFSDFSDFSDFSFSFD_FSDFSDF
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```